# How do I find the orientation of a PDF using PHP or a Linux script?

Tags: php, linux, pdf

I need to scan an uploaded PDF to determine if the pages within are all portrait or if there are any landscape pages.  Is there someway I can use PHP or a linux command to scan the PDF for these pages?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### (Updated answer -- scroll down...)

You can use either `pdfinfo` (part of either the *poppler-utils* or the *xpdf-tools*) or `identify` (part of the ImageMagick toolkit).

### identify:

```
identify -format "%f  Page %s:   Width: %W -- Height: %H\n" T-VD7.PDF
```

Example output:

```
T-VD7.PDF  Page 0:  Width: 595 -- Height: 842
T-VD7.PDF  Page 1:  Width: 595 -- Height: 842
T-VD7.PDF  Page 2:  Width: 1191 -- Height: 842
[...]
T-VD7.PDF  Page 11:  Width: 595 -- Height: 421
T-VD7.PDF  Page 12:  Width: 595 -- Height: 842
```

Or a bit simpler:

```
identify -format "%s: %Wx%H\n" T-VD7.PDF
```

gives:

```
0:  595x842
1:  595x842
2:  1191x842
[...]
11:  595x421
12:  595x842
```

**Note**, how `identify` uses a zero-based page counting mechanism!

Pages are 'landscape' if their width is bigger than their height. They are neither-nor, if both are equal.

The advantage is that `identify` lets you tweak the output format quite easily and very extensively.

### pdfinfo:

```
pdfinfo input.pdf | grep "Page.*size:"
```

Example output:

```
Page size:      595.276 x 841.89 pts (A4)
```

`pdfinfo` is definitely *faster* and also more *precise* than `identify`, if it comes to multi-page PDFs. (*The 13-page PDF I tested this with took `identify` to 31 seconds to process, whereas `pdfinfo` needed less than half a second....*)

**Be warned:** by default `pdfinfo` does report the size for the ***first page only***. To get sizes for *all* pages (as you may know, there are PDFs which use mixed page sizes as well as mixed orientations), you have to modify the command:

```
pdfinfo -f 3 -l 13 input.pdf | grep "Page.*size:"
```

Output now:

```
Page    1 size: 595.276 x 841.89 pts (A4)
Page    2 size: 595.276 x 841.89 pts (A4)
Page    3 size: 1191 x 842 pts (A3)
[....]
Page   12 size: 595 x 421 pts (A5)
Page   13 size: 595.276 x 841.89 pts (A4)
```

This will print the sizes of page 3 (**f** irst to report) through page 13 (**l** ast to report).

### Scripting it:

```
  pdfinfo \
    -f 1 \
    -l 1000 \
     Vergleich-VD7.PDF \
| grep "Page.* size:" \
| \
| while read Page _pageno size _width x _height rest; do 
  [ "$(echo "${_width} / 1"|bc)" -gt "$(echo "${_height} / 1"|bc)" ] \
     && echo "Page $_pageno is landscape..." \
    || echo "Page $_pageno is portrait..."  ; \
 done
```

(the `bc`-trick is required because the `-gt` comparison works for the shell only with integers. Dividing by `1` with `bc` will take round the possible real values to integers...)

Result:

```
Page 1 is portrait...
Page 2 is portrait...
Page 3 is landscape...
[...]
Page 12 is landscape...
Page 13 is portrait...
```

---

## Update: Using the 'right' `pdfinfo` to discover page rotations...

My initial answer tooted the horn of `pdfinfo`. Serenade X says in a comment that his/her problem is to discover *rotated* pages.

Ok now, here is some additional info which is not yet known widely and therefor has not yet been really absorbed by all `pdfinfo` users...

As I mentioned, there are two different `pdfinfo` utilities around:

1. the one which comes as part of the `xpdf-utils` package (on some platform also named `xpdf-tools`).
2. the one which comes as part of the `poppler-utils` package (on some platforms also named `poppler-tools`, and sometimes it is not separated out as a packages but is part of the main `poppler` package).

#### Poppler's `pdfinfo` output

So here is a sample output from Poppler's `pdfinfo` command. The tested file is a 2-page PDF where the first page is in portrait A4 and the second page is in landscape A4 format:

```
kp@mbp:~$  pdfinfo -f 1 -l 2 a4portrait+landscape.pdf 
Producer:       GPL Ghostscript 9.05
CreationDate:   Thu Jul 26 14:23:31 2012
ModDate:        Thu Jul 26 14:23:31 2012
Tagged:         no
Form:           none
Pages:          2
Encrypted:      no
Page    1 size: 595 x 842 pts (A4)
Page    1 rot:  0
Page    2 size: 842 x 595 pts (A4)
Page    2 rot:  0
File size:      3100 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.4
```

Do you see the lines saying `Page    1 rot:  0` and `Page    2 rot:  0`?

Do you notice the lines saying `Page    1 size: 595 x 842 pts (A4)` and `Page    2 size: 842 x 595 pts (A4)` and the differences between the two?

#### XPDF's `pdfinfo` output

Now let's compare this to the output of XPDF's `pdfinfo`:

```
kp@mbp:~$  xpdf-pdfinfo -f 1 -l 2 a4portrait+landscape.pdf 
Producer:       GPL Ghostscript 9.05
CreationDate:   Thu Jul 26 14:23:31 2012
ModDate:        Thu Jul 26 14:23:31 2012
Tagged:         no
Pages:          2
Encrypted:      no
Page    1 size: 595 x 842 pts (A4)
Page    2 size: 842 x 595 pts (A4)
File size:      3100 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.4
```

You may notice *one more* difference, if you look closely enough. I won't point my finger to it, and will keep my mouth shut for now... :-)

#### Poppler's `pdfinfo` correctly reports rotation of page 2

Next, I rotate the second page of the file by 90 degrees using `pdftk` (I don't have Adobe Acrobat around):

```
pdftk \
  a4portrait+landscape.pdf \
  cat 1 2E \
  output a4portrait+landscape---page2-landscaped-by-pdftk.pdf
```

Now Poppler's `pdfinfo` reports this:

```
kp@mbp:~$  pdfinfo -f 1 -l 2 a4portrait+landscape---page2-landscaped-by-pdftk.pdf 
Creator:        pdftk 1.44 - www.pdftk.com
Producer:       itext-paulo-155 (itextpdf.sf.net-lowagie.com)
CreationDate:   Thu Jul 26 14:39:47 2012
ModDate:        Thu Jul 26 14:39:47 2012
Tagged:         no
Form:           none
Pages:          2
Encrypted:      no
Page    1 size: 595 x 842 pts (A4)
Page    1 rot:  0
Page    2 size: 842 x 595 pts (A4)
Page    2 rot:  90
File size:      1759 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.4
```

As you can see, the line `Page    2 rot:  90` tells us what we are looking for. XPDF's `pdfinfo` would essentially report the same info about the changed file as it does about the original one. Of course, it would still correctly capture the changed `Creator:`, `Producer:` and `*Date:` infos, but it would miss the rotated page...

**Also note this detail: page 2 originally was designed as a landscape page, which can be seen from the `Page    2 size: 842 x 595 pts (A4)` info part. However, it shows up in the current PDF as a portrait page, as can be seen by the `Page    2 rot:  90` part.**

Also note that there are 4 different values that could appear for the rotation info:

- `0` (no rotation),
- `90` (rotation to the East, or 90 degrees clockwise),
- `180` (rotation to the South, tumbled page image, upside-down, or 180 degrees clockwise),
- `270` (rotation to the West, or 90 degrees counter-clockwise, or 270 degrees clockwise).

### Some Background Info

[Popper](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/releases.html) (developed by [*The Poppler Developers*](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/)) is a fork of [XPDF](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html) (developed by [*Glyph & Cog LLC*](http://www.glyphandcog.com/)), that happened around 2005. (As one of their important reason for their forking the Poppler developer at the time gave: Glyph & Cog didn't always provide timely bugfixes for security-related problems...)

Anyway, the Poppler fork for a very long time kept the associated commandline utilities, their commandline parameters and syntax as well as the format of their output compatible to the original (XPDF/Glyph & Cog LLC) ones.

#### Existing Poppler tools gaining additional features over competing XPDF tools

However, more recently they started to add additional features. Out of the top of my head:

- `pdfinfo` now also reports the *rotation* status of each page (starting with Poppler v0.19.0, released March 1st, 2012).
- `pdffonts` now also reports the *font encoding* for each font (starting with Poppler v0.19.1, released March 15th, 2012).

#### Poppler tools getting more siblings

The Poppler tools also provide some extra commandline utilities which are not in the original XPDF package (some of which have been added only quite recently):

- `pdftocairo` - utility for creating PNG, JPEG, PostScript, EPS, PDF, SVG (using Cairo)
- `pdfseparate` - utility to extract PDF pages
- `pdfunite` - utility to merge PDF files
- `pdfdetach` - utility to list or extract embedded files from a PDF
- `pdftohtml` - utility to convert HTML from PDF files

Comment: pdfinfo has been working great, however, whenever we upload a PDF that has pages that were rotated in Adobe Acrobat, it won't detect the orientation properly.  pdfinfo sees them in the original dimensions before they were rotated.  Any ideas?

Comment: @Serenade X: Can you provide a sample PDF which displays this behavior?

Comment: @Serenade X: It could be the case that Acrobat didn't *really* rotate the page. Instead it flagged the page as *"Display this page in a viewer as rotated by 90 degrees"*. But I cannot tell for sure without having access to a small sample of such a PDF.

Comment: Ok I haven't tried what you said yet, but here is a link to a PDF.  The first page is rotated clockwise. [PDF](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9rgl3ly5vx4of1b/testrot.pdf)

Comment: Ok the tool that I have been using is actually the poppler-utils pdfinfo.  It is not reporting the rotation.  Ubuntu says it is at the latest version.  I am not sure how to check the version of poppler-utils but ubuntu doesn't say there is an update for it.

Comment: Don't use that last link for the PDF use [this one](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9rgl3ly5vx4of1b/testrot.pdf)

Comment: @Serenade X: I very clearly stated which version of Poppler started to report the rotation: *'v0.19.0, released March 1st, 2012'*. To determine your version, just run `pdfinfo -v`... Both your links give me HTML document, not PDF.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I wasn't sure how to find the version.  I will manually update it seeing as I'm running 0.18.4. Thanks for all your help. [Try this link](http://printandmail.byu.edu/Theses/testrot.pdf)

Comment: Ok I finally got it installed and now it is reporting the rotations in addition to the dimensions.  Thanks a ton @Kurt Pfeifle.

Comment: @KurtPfeifle I tried the code to identify the orientation but no luck. There are three pages which are landscape but all 119 page show same page size ...Can you please help

Answer (score 3):

`identify` which comes with ImageMagick will give you the width and height of a given PDF file (it also requires GhostScript be installed on the system).

```
$ identify -format "%g\n" FILENAME.PDF
1417x1106+0+0
```

Where `1417` is the width, `1106` is the height, and you (for this purpose) can ignore the `+0+0`.

*Edit:* Sorry, I was referring to **Mike B**'s comment on the original question - as he said, after knowing the width and height you can determine if you have a portrait or landscape image (if height > width then portrait else landscape).

Also, the `\n` added to the `-format` argument (as suggested by Kurt Pfeifle) will separate each page into its own line.  He also mentions the `%W` and `%H` format parameters; all the possible format parameters can be found [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/escape.php) (there are a lot of them).

Comment: I advice you to add a `"\n"` to the end of your `-format` spec. Otherwise you'll get an unpleasant surprise for multipage PDF results. And otherwise I won't upvote your answer... :-)

Comment: Also, if you want to avoid the `+0+0` parts (which are useless here), better use `-format "%W %H\n"`...

Comment: @KurtPfeifle I just happened to remember `"%g"` off the top of my head as I use it in one of my applications (where I actually *do* need the +0+0, since in my case they rarely *are* +0+0).